# R version of CASE-WHEN from SQL

Tags: r, switch-statement, if-statement

I am looking for a way in R to accomplish something similar to the CASE - WHEN functionality in SQL. There is a variable related to an income range, and I need to create two new variables whose values are the min and max of the range. The code below is not quite R and not quite SQL, but something in the middle. Hopefully it is clear what I am trying to do.

> if (INCOME_CD == "A") {
>       income.min <- 1000
>       income.max <- 14999
>   } else if (INCOME_CD == "B") {
>       income.min <- 15000
>       income.max <- 24999
>   .
>   .
>   } else {
>       income.min <- 99999
>       income.max <- 999999
>   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `switch`

Here the last value is the default

```
switch (INCOME_CD , 
        A= list(income.min = 1000,income.max = 14999),
        B =list(income.min = 15000, income.max = 24999),
        list(income.min = 99999,income.max = 999999))
```

e.g

```
INCOME_CD <- 'A'
```

the code above returns

```
$income.min
[1] 1000
$income.max
[1] 14999
```

**EDIT clarification to the OP**

generally we use this code in a function.

```
get.income <- function(INCOME_CD){
switch (INCOME_CD , 
        A= list(income.min = 1000,income.max = 14999),
        B =list(income.min = 15000, income.max = 24999),
        list(income.min = 99999,income.max = 999999))
}

> get.income('A')
$income.min
[1] 1000

$income.max
[1] 14999

> get.income('B')
$income.min
[1] 15000

$income.max
[1] 24999

> get.income('C')
$income.min
[1] 99999

$income.max
[1] 999999
```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen a couple examples of `switch` but it didn't look like it did what I was looking for.

Comment: I tried the code above and R gave me this error message: EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Comment: @Oliver are u sure?! try it again. did you give a value to INCOME_CD before calling the switch part? I edit my question. Hope it is clear now!

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering about that. How do I get this to go through each row in a data frame and assign the two new values?

Comment: @Oliver it is better that you try it by yourself and ask  a new question if you can't.  wondering about that ?? you are really confusing.

Comment: I will accept that your solution is good and the biggest problem is that I really only know enough of R to be dangerous.